# Is there a way to pass an argument to the is operator?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to find an alternative to the following so that I can take advantage of the `is` operator.

```
public bool IsOfType(Type type)
{
    return this._item.GetType() == type;
}
```

Something similar to the following, which does not compile.

```
public bool IsOfType(Type type)
{
    return this._item is type;
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx):

```
public bool IsOfType(Type type)
{
    return _item != null && type.IsAssignableFrom(_item.GetType());
}
```

Or if you can make the method generic, that's simpler as you *can* use `is` with a type parameter:

```
public bool IsOfType<T>()
{
    return _item is T;
}
```

EDIT: As noted in Wim's answer, there's also [`Type.IsInstanceOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype.aspx) which makes the non-generic method simpler:

```
public bool IsOfType(Type type)
{
    return type.InstanceOf(_item);
}
```

Comment: Just about to post the generics alternative... Why did I had to see the updated answer? :)

Comment: I always disliked InstanceOf syntax, it's almost worth making this an extension method on `object` just to avoid it.

Comment: @demoncodemonkey: Yes, I know what you mean. Obviously the syntax itself couldn't have been improved back in .NET 1.0, but I wonder if there's a better name available...

Comment: The name is confusing. Besides, this answer has a typo, omitting the first two letters of `IsInstanceOf`. Also the name `IsAssignableFrom` is, to me, confusing. I always have to think twice to figure our is it's `t.IsAssignableFrom(s)` or `s.IsAssignableFrom(t)` I need.

Comment: @Jeppe: a trick I always use with x.IsAssignableFrom(y) is that you could perform a rewrite in your head to: X x = (X) y; and then reason if that would be OK or not. That's actually why they chose this name I guess. Ergo, y.IsInstanceOfType(x) <==> x.IsAssignableFrom(y).

Comment: @Wim.van.Gool However, both `typeof(object).IsInstanceOfType("hello")` and `typeof(object).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string))` return ***true***, so in a sense they go "the same way". So your last bi-implication can be misleading.

Comment: @Jeppe: you're right, but it's the Type.IsInstanceOf(object) that has the misleading signature, as mentioned above. It should actually be Object.IsInstanceOf(Type) :)

Answer (score 12):

You can do multiple things, depending on the context:

- Use `Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)` if all you've got is two type-instances.
- Use `Type.IsInstanceOf(object instance)` if you have access to an instance to compare.
- Use generics like:

  > ```
  > public bool IsOfType<T>()
  > {
  >     return this._item is T;
  > }
  > ```

Comment: I'd forgotten about Type.IsInstanceOf. Doh! Will edit my answer with a complete example of that...

Comment: It's actually called `IsInstanceOfType`, not just `IsInstanceOf`.